# Turn off vi capablilites of ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, vim, terminal, vi

Recently I came across a great command which powers up terminal with VI shortcuts.

`set -o vi`

However, I am unable to unset this for current shell. 
There is no help on `man set` or `man unset` or any online resource.

It would be of great help to know more about this stuff.

One can the see on/off status by using `set -o`

Comment: Doesn't `set +o vi` work? ([doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html))

Comment: @Norman yes that works !  whats the significance of `+` sign  ?

Comment: "Using ‘+’ rather than ‘-’ causes these options to be turned off."

Comment: Ok I did not see you attached the doc ! . . my bad

Comment: No problem, I shouldn't put links at end of sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the default, which happens to be emacs mode:

```
set -o emacs
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you've got a .inputrc file in your home directory.  It's probably set within that.  If not, try:

grep vi$ .*

That should find where this is set.